# Why is the covariant derivative defined as $\nabla_{X}Y=P((X\otimes I)Y)$, projection onto the space of all vector fields, in this wikipedia article?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensor-products, connections

In the Wikipedia article [Riemannian connection on a surface](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Riemannian_connection_on_a_surface#/Covariant_derivative), I am struggling to interpret the following:

"Since $\mathcal X(M)$ is a submodule of $C^\infty(M,\mathbf E^3)=C^\infty(M)\otimes \mathbf E^3$, the operator $X\otimes I$ is defined on $\mathcal X(M)$, taking values in $C^\infty(M,\mathbf E^3)$.

Let $P$ be the smooth map from $M$ into $M_3(\mathbf R)$ such that $P(p)$ is the orthogonal projection of $\mathbf E^3$ onto the tangent space at $p$. Thus for the unit normal vector $\mathbf{n}_p$ at $p$, uniquely defined up to a sign, and $\mathbf v$ in $\mathbf E^3$, the projection is given by $P(p)(\mathbf v) = \mathbf v - (\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{n}_p)\mathbf{n}_p$

Pointwise multiplication by $P$ gives a $C^\infty(M)$-module map of $C^\infty(M, \mathbf E^3)$ onto $\mathcal{X}(M)$ . The assignment
$$
    \nabla_X Y = P((X\otimes I)Y). 
$$
defines an operator $\nabla_X$ on $\mathcal{X}(M)$ called the covariant derivative, satisfying the following properties ..."

In particular, what is this the operator $X \otimes I$? Also, how can I relate this notion of covariant derivative to the one given in [Covariant derivative](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Covariant_derivative) or in do Carmo's "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces"?

Comment: You can define it any way you want. What do you want it to achieve?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, your question asks, what the operator $I$ is. It is not explicitly mentioned but $I:M\to \mathbb E^3$ is the inclusion map.

Comment: Thank you @frog. So does $X\otimes I$ eat a vector field and return a smooth $\mathbb{E}^3$-valued function on $M$? Also would it be correct to interpret $X\otimes I$ as a sort of derivative operator?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, the map $X\otimes I$ takes a vector field $Y$ on $M$ as its input and returns $X(Y)$, a map that sends a point $p\in M$ to $X(Y)(p)$ in the sense of directional derivatives. The point is that the vector $X(Y)(p)$ is not necessarily an element of $T_pM$ but rather of $T_p\mathbb E^3$. Applying $P$ to it, projects the vector orthogonally onto $T_pM$, and therefore, $P((X\otimes I)Y)$ is again a vector field on $M$.

Answer (score 0):

You're right: That part of the wikipedia article is badly written, indeed. :-(
It does not explain its notation (e.g. $M_3(R)$) and it does not specify whether the tensor product is to be $\otimes_R$ or $\otimes_{C^\infty(M,R)}$. In fact, $X$ is an $R$-linear map of $C^\infty(M,R)$ into itself, but it is a derivation on $C^\infty(M,R)$, so it is not $C^\infty(M,R)$-linear (in general).

There is no unique way how, given $X$, a derivation operator on vector fields on $M$ is induced. In fact, the Lie derivative would be $[X,Y]$, but also any covariant derivative could be taken.

The article should explain, how the induced Riemannian connection is obtained, and this is indeed obtained by taking (pointwise on $M$) the orthogonal projection in the restricted (to $M$) tangent bundle $T_ME^3$ of $E^3$ onto the tangent bundle $TM$ of $M$.

Probably, the operation $X(Y)$ should read $D_X(Y)$, the covariant derivative, in the surrounding space $E^3$, of $Y$ in the direction of $X$. In order to make sense, at first, the vector field $Y$ on $M$ should be extended smoothly to a tubular neighbourhood of $M$, open in $E^3$. Then one can compute locally in $E^3$ the differential $DY$, and finally, one takes the differential into the direction of $X$. The result is independent of the extension of $Y$ chosen.

So, if $X$ is a vector at $x \in M$, tangent to $M$, we compute in $E^3$ the derivative $$D_X(Y)(x) = DY(x)(X) = X \lrcorner DY(x).$$ Then, the covariant derivative on $M$ is
$$\nabla_X(Y)(x) = P_x(D_X(Y)(x)) = P_x(DY(x)(X)) = P_x(X \lrcorner DY(x))$$
where $P_x$ is the orthogonal projection in the vector space $R^3$ (considered as the tangent space $T_xE^3$) onto the vector space of directions tangent to $M$ at $x$, i.e. onto $T_xM$.
This can be done pointwise for every $x \in M$.

I guess, the author of that part of the wikipedia article wanted to think of $Y$ as an $R^3$-vector valued differential 0-form on $M$ and then considered a derivation on such vector valued forms into the direction of $X$, induced by using the covariant differential of the surrounding $E^3$.

Moreover, the wikipedia article does not distinguish clearly between an affine Euclidean space (a metric-affine space of points) and a Euclidean vector space (a vector space with a Euclidean scalar product and a Euclidean norm). It is, of course, not forbidden to embed a surface $M$ into a Euclidean vector space (of translations... :-) ), but usually the surface $M$ is given as embedded in *affine* Euclidean space, which is by far more natural. (e.g. one cannot compute the sum of two points, but one can compute the sum of two vectors).

Finally, the wikipedia article later on treats only **oriented** embedded surfaces. The method described there cannot be applied globally on a Moebius strip, for instance.

I'd consider rewriting that wikipedia article and providing full definitions of all symbols used.